# Como imprimir elementos de uma lista na ordem inversa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, for

Criei um programa que recebe inteiros do usuário e os imprime de volta na ordem inversa que os recebeu, no entanto meu programa não está retornando todos os inteiros que recebe. Quando insiro 9 inteiros por exemplo, ele imprime apenas 5.

```
    i = int(input('Digite um número: '))
lista = []

while i > 0:
    lista.append(i)
    i = int(input('Digite um número: '))

for i in lista:
    print(lista[-1])
    del(lista[-1])
```

[image: Exemplo]

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Se pode usar algo pronto tem pelo menos duas técnicas:

```
lista = []
while True:
    i = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    if i < 1: break
    lista.append(i)
for i in lista[::-1]:
    print(i)
for i in reversed(lista):
    print(i)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IkS9yU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ReverseListpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/ReverseList.py).

Ambas geram um iterador para a lista na ordem invertida. A primeira usa o *slice* para indicar que começa vai do início ao fim já que não foi colocado uma posição de início e fim antes dos dois sinais de `:` e no final coloca de quanto em quanto ele deve andar, portanto mostra que deve ir em posição negativa, assim indica que deve ir decrementando cada posição.

Nunca altere a composição de um objeto complexo como uma lista durante o laço, principalmente apagando itens, isso quase sempre dará errado porque o iterador estava preparado para algo que não existe mais. Você pode alterar os dados internos, mas não a lista, como foi feito.

Além disso o problema pede para imprimir invertido e não ficar apagando os dados.

Eu modifiquei o laço porque eu acho errado pedir o dado dentro e fora do laço (veja [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101)). Em um exemplo simples pode até não causar problemas, mas vai acostumando errado. Aí resolvi alguns outros problemas que acontecia no código, mas não é o foco da pergunta.

Não considerei que a digitação pode ser errada e quebrar a aplicação, o correto é tratar isso capturando exceção, ou criando uma função própria que lide melhor com isso.

Se o problema impedisse usar algum recurso próprio da linguagem aí teria que iterar cada item começando pelo último até o primeiro, tendo um contador para controlar isso, mas em códigos reais essa restrição não faz sentido.

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que em:

```
for i in lista:
    print(lista[-1])
    del(lista[-1])
```

A cada iteração, o último valor na lista é excluído, por exemplo, a lista vai ser, no final de todas as suas inserções:
`[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.

No `for`, ao iterar o 9, o 1 será deletado, ao iterar o 8, o 2 será deletado, e assim sucessivamente. Quando chegar no valor 5, este será o último valor a ser iterado.

Comment: Se está fazendo `del(lista[-1])`, por que seria o primeiro elemento que seria excluído? A resposta não faz sentido algum.

Comment: Então, jovem, acontece que o '-1' e a posição de leitura reversa da lista, ```del(lista[-1[)``` é o mesmo que realizar um lista.pop(), que resulta na remoção do item. Caso você insista, é só fazer uma parada em cada iteração e você verá que é exatamente o que está acontecendo.

Comment: A resposta do Maniero faz exatamente o que o St3h quer fazer, o que eu fiz foi elucidar o motivo pelo qual o teste dele está resultando em algo que não é esperado.

Comment: Mas a explicação está errada. Em nenhum momento os primeiros valores são removidos. É exibido o 9 e o remove da lista; é exibido o 8 e o remove da lista... o problema está em iterar a lista e alterá-la ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Ao fazer `i in lista`, `i` valerá 1 e será exibido o 9, removendo-o; depois `i` vale 2 e exibe o 8, removendo-o; depois `i` vale 3 exibindo o 7, removendo-o; depois `i` vale 4 exibindo o 6, removendo-o; depois `i` vale 5, exibindo o 5, removendo-o. Como os valores 6, 7, 8 e 9 foram removidos, o laço é encerrado.

Comment: A questão é a leitura reversa.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão devemos montar **2** laços de repetições. Um para montar a lista e outro para ler e exibir os valores da lista em ordem inversa.

Pois bem, para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
i = int(input('Digite um número: '))
lista = list()
while len(lista) < i:
    lista.append(int(input(f'Digite {len(lista) + 1}º número: ')))

while len(lista) >= 1:
    print(f'O {len(lista)}º elemento da lista é: {lista[-1]}')
    del(lista[-1])
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/ewkycgem-solkarped) o funcionamento do código.

Observe que quando executamos o código devemos inserir a quantidade de elementos da lista. Posteriormente, devemos digitar cada um dos `n` valores e pressionar `enter`.

Em seguida os elementos da lista são exibidos em ordem inversa de inserção.